# Directory issues within Pycharm (free version) & Perforce

Tags: python, pycharm, perforce, pyscripter

Ok, so I'm looking to switch to PyCharm from PyScripter for OS independent development. I also wanted to mention that I'm using Perforce for version control.

So what I currently do is double click a .py for editing in Perforce, and PyScripter opens up and I edit to my hearts desire. I can click on an imported function, and it'll open up the corresponding .py file and bring me right to the function. Awesome.

So I have yet to be able to achieve that on PyCharm. I'm using the community version which should be just fine for what I want, which is just an editor with some python checking & built in console.

When I set the default .py program to use in Perforce to PyCharm, I click on the .py and PyCharm fires up. Good so far. But my problem arises when I try to "ctrl + click" a function or method. I get the "Cannot find declaration to go to." I import the associated class & file.

*(Just an example, not actual code).* So in Transportation.py I have "import Cars", which is a .py. I do Cars.NumberOfDoors() and I get the above error. My folder structure is:

- Scripts (folder)

  - Population.py (General support script)
  - Citybudget.py (General support script)
  - MassTransit (folder)

    - Transportation.py
    - Cars.py

So question boils down to, is how do I properly setup the root to be the Scripts folder when I click on a file from Perforce? How do I set it up that it recognizes where it's at in the folder structure? So if I'm in the MassTransit it'll set the root as Scripts folder, and same for if I'm accessing the general support scripts like Population.py?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> File --> Open

in Pycharm and select your Scripts(folder) and open it. Then the Pycharm will treat it as a project and you will be able to `ctrl + click` a function.

Comment: I understand that is a way, but I was hoping for a little bit more fluid process like how I currently have it set up. With double click file in Perforce , PyScripter opens and recognizes its place in the folder structure and automatically does all that for me. 

I have quite a few workspaces in Perforce and hop around quite a bit in a day so doing it automatically rather than the manual method, as recommended by you, is really what I'm trying to get some advice on. That is, if it's even possible.

Comment: you have `Car.NumberOfDoors()` shouldn't it be `Cars.NumberOfDoors()` ? Is it the reason? I have tried opening as you said without opening as a project but that way also worked.

Comment: My bad. I didn't state that that was simply an example, not actual code. I have to believe I might not have some setting or something set correctly and I don't know what but I'm just lost as to what.

Comment: I do see when I open up the file from perforce, pycharm makes a prject called Transportation.py0.tmp. In PyCharm are the projects always located in the AppData\Local\Temp\--project name--? When I got to the structure, I only see Transportation.py and it is correctly referenced to the location of the script in the MassTransit folder. Also I hover over the import Cars and it says no module found.